# How can I create a select menu in a python script?

Tags: python, menu

I'm creating a simple python script and I want to create a select menu in it, like this:

```
 "Choose your option:"

1) Option 1   2) Option 2   3) Option 3   4) Quit
```

And according to user's choice, I want different actions to be executed.

ty :)

Comment: i dont no have a code i demende how to create this im a noob :)

Comment: isn't it too simple? you can do that yourselft with `choose=input(`Option 1 2 3`)` and `if choose == i` or `dict` to  do whatever you want

Comment: you have a documentation  a demo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in the console, you can use raw_input("Prompt") Like as stated in the answer above. In Python 3, the raw_input() function was deprecated so you'll have to just use input(). After your raw_input function, you could then use an If statement to evaluate the answer the user inputs.
example:

```
question = raw_input("How old are you?")

if question == "10":
    print "You are 10 years old."
else:
    print "You are not 10 years old."
```

It's also important to mention that the raw_input() function saves the input as a `str`ing, so if a number is expected, make sure you account for that using `int()` or `float()`

If you do not want to do it in the console, and you want to have an actual Window and buttons, you could learn how to use GUI packages for Python. tkinter is a good one that comes with Python, which I'm currently learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can get input from the user with `raw_input`. Here's the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) (always a good thing to read!). You can use it like this:

```
option = raw_input("Choose your option: ")
```

Whatever the user types will be stored in `option` for you to use later. If you want to convert the input to a number, you can do `int(option)`.

(By the way, it's safer to get in the habit of using `raw_input` rather than `input` because a malicious user could type any code they want at an `input` prompt and it would be run.)

Comment: ok thank you I am going to read it and try something :)

Comment: Cool. :) If my answer helped you, you should mark it as correct using the checkmark on the left side.

Comment: is possible to mark 2 solution ?